# Swift - Validating address to use with GMS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I have an app I'm making where the user will create an event. The user will enter the address of the event in 4 fields, 'Number', 'Street', 'Town/City', and 'Postal Code'.

The address will be stored in a database, and then called from the database to be used to place a marker on a map using the google maps sdk.

I have tried to validate the address by using CLLocation and geocoding the address to see if it returns a hit, and if not it would return an error, but even when inputting real addresses I'm still getting the error.

I'm away from my computer right now, so can post code if needed later, but for now, has anyone got a way that will definitely work? Is there a way to validate the address to make sure it's real?

EDIT**

```
func forwardGeocoding(address: String) {
    CLGeocoder().geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
        if error != nil {
            self.alert(message: "Have you entered your address correctly?", title: "Invalid Address")
            self.coordinates.latitude = 0.0
            self.coordinates.longitude = 0.0
        }
        if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {
            let placemark = placemarks?[0]
            let location = placemark?.location
            let coordinate = location?.coordinate
            self.coordinates = (location?.coordinate)!

    }
    }

}


@IBAction func didTapCreate(_ sender: Any) {

    if ((houseNumber.text?.characters.count)! > 0 && (streetInput.text?.characters.count)! > 0 && (cityInput.text?.characters.count)! > 0 && (postcodeInput.text?.characters.count)! > 0)
    {
        let address = "\(houseNumber.text) \(streetInput.text), \(cityInput.text)"

        self.forwardGeocoding(address: address)

        if (coordinates.latitude == 0.0 && coordinates.longitude == 0.0)
        {
            self.alert(message: "Have you entered your address correctly?", title: "Invalid Address")
        }
        else
        {
            let key = self.dbRef.child("events").childByAutoId().key

            let childUpdates = ["/events/\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)/\(key)/address":address, "/events/\(self.loggedInUser!.uid)/\(key)/date":dateInput.text] as [String : Any]

            self.dbRef.updateChildValues(childUpdates)

            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
    }
}
```

I've changed the alert's to have a number on the end of each to debug which it's getting caught at, and it seems like it is getting caught at the create button alert, meaning the lat and long are being set to 0.0 even though there is no error

Comment: The snarky answer will be 'no', since there is no practical way to determine with near certainty, whether a string is a valid address. A geocoder is the right way to go; I'm wondering whether you're having trouble setting it up correctly?

Comment: Will edit the question with code soon

Comment: @dylanthelion question has been updated with my code for the geocoding and my button for creating the event

Comment: Your use of the Geocoder is fine. I double-checked, by adding it to a blank app, passed in my own address, and printed out the longitude. Perhaps it's the address String? I'm assuming that your code is going into your Geocoder error block, here.

Comment: It's getting caught in the if statement under didTapCreate, as it's showing the error message. But if I dismiss the error and press the button again, the address is pushed through to the database no problem? So it seems to be that the lat and long are 0.0 and then also populated on the second press?

Comment: Ah. I think I know the problem (I've hit it several times, building location-based apps). Are you using CLLocationManager to get the user's location, and are you first calling startUpdatingLocation() in this VC?

Comment: Nope I'm not getting the users location at all, the code above is the only usage of location and that's to geocode the address into latitude and longitude values, would it have anything to do with it being asynchronous? Would that cause it to get caught in the if statement?

Comment: Okay, missed that. Can you set a break point, and figure out exactly where the code is going wrong? That will help a ton.

Comment: As far as I understand it, I click the button and it goes into the function to geocode the address, but before that is finished it goes ahead into the if statement where the coordinates will be 0 as the result from the function hasn't been returned yet, so I basically need a way to stop it from going into the if statement until the function is complete. Would it be wise to remove the geocoding function and simply perform that task in the main function before the if statement?

Comment: If you're certain that's what is going wrong, you should rewrite your forwardGeocoding func, so that it takes a closure as a parameter, then pass it the if..else, in a closure. That way, you can control when the if..else is run.

Comment: I'll give that a go and get back to you, thanks!